# How to predict & control ghost movement in Pac-Man

Tags: arcade, pac-man

Billy Mitchell was the first person to achieve a perfect score in the arcade game Pac-Man.

Back in 2008, there was an article published entitled [*"The Perfect Man - How Billy Mitchell became a video-game superstar and achieved Pac-Man bliss"* by David Ramsey.](https://web.archive.org/web/20080229043301/http://www.oxfordamericanmag.com/content.cfm?ArticleID=58&Entry=Home)

When questioned about the use of hiding spots in Pac-Man, Mitchell replied:

> "You don't use the hiding spots. Someone doesn't use them. I use them. I could show you how, but you wouldn't be able to do it."

The article continued:

> While a crappy video-game player can improve, Mitchell's level of arcade mastery, he is convinced, cannot be taught.

**I am interested in some clearly written instruction on predicting/controlling ghost movement, and using the hiding spots in Pac-Man.**

Now, I've read the whole article, and watched many videos of Mitchell playing video games. They are fun and interesting to watch, but they don't really teach or educate. *(It does no good to say "Just do what I'm doing" ... there needs to be explanation and instruction. I can watch what you're doing, but have no idea how you're doing it!)*

For most of us, trained ability will not even come close to the level of his natural aptitude. However, I still believe that even crappy players can learn some (though maybe not all) of the "impossible" tricks with a bit of help and practice.

Comment: [The Pac-Man Dossier](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132330/the_pacman_dossier.php) gives comprehensive insight into the game's mechanics including each ghost's behavior.

Comment: Wow. I am glad I asked this question. And now, based on reading through [The Pac-Man Dossier](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132330/the_pacman_dossier.php), I am also voting to close my own question as too broad.

Comment: This question could be simplified to ask how ghosts work, which can be answered (imo) in the space of a single SE answer -- this mostly would involve per-ghost target selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the [The Pac-Man Dossier](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132330/the_pacman_dossier.php), as suggested in the comments, I understand a little more about how broad this question actually is. I expected several layers of explanation, but a proper answer really depends on comprehensive insight into nearly every one of the game's mechanics.

*(The dossier is long & detailed. There is no easy way to copy just the relevant portions; and putting all of it here in a readable format would probably be flagrant plagiarism, and is not a good fit for this site.)*